# Can I use pavers as a cheap solution to stop rain water erosion?

Tags: pavers

After over a decade of rain water running down from the roof, I have a small 'moat' around the house, where the water has eroded away the grass and sand (this is Florida, soil is sandy) - see Picture 1. Also, water gets splattered against the house wall, keeping it wet throughout rainy season, which is not a good thing long-term - this is the main concern now.

Adding gutters would cost significantly, so I came up with a cheaper solution:
Simply place a row of pavers with a slight outward tilt along the house, which will catch the falling water's impact, and run it off in the grass or splatter it outwards (hence the slight tilt) - see picture 2.

[image]

**The question is - will that work as expected?**

- it took the water over a decade to erode through the grass and about two inches deep, so it's not that bad
- nobody will ever walk on them, so the pavers do not need to support that. Therefore, I plan to simple place them in the sandy dirt, next to each other.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm no pro, but it sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: I think a paver at an angle like you show would work, I would check on the cost of gutters compared to pavers it might not be much of a difference and gutters would improve the value of your home.

Comment: I think it'll just move the problem but will help.  Put in gutters and then pipe it away from the house into a garden would be a better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this years ago along one side of my home and it's worked well.  The area between the pavers and the house you'll want to turn into a little flower bed or mulch it over as trying to mow it can be a pain (was for me anyway).

I also put some pavers at the end of my downspouts to prevent erosion there.  A few on the ground then one on top so the water coming out of the spout will hit the top one to slow it down then run off the bottom ones into the ground.

Answer (score 6):

The pavers will definitely take care of the moat and deflect the rain water. However, you will still get some rain from the roof hitting the pavers and splashing against your wall. Don't forget about the wind, rain doesn't usually fall straight down so you'll get that wetness too. Long term solution would be gutters.

Comment: I've seen gravel used as an alternative; same effect, less splash.

Answer (score 0):

I like the pavers scheme.

How about this addition: between every 3-4 pavers plant a bush or one of those big agaves, or alternate them for variety.  You are in Florida and so if you amend the soil you can grow anything.  When the plants grow in, their leaves will slow the force of the descending water and big agaves would be perfect for this.   Their leaves are strong.

If you get the right kind of plants (or agaves) they will obscure the pavers underneath in case anyone thinks they are ugly.  Keep plants trimmed back from the wall of the house so it can breathe.